# Set range to value without re-formatting cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range of numbers with some `/` in it that I am trying to copy to another range:

```
...
152/7163
152/7163
153/7163
153/7163
48/7164
332/7138
332/7138
332/7138
371/7166
5/7161
5/7161
5/7161
5/7161
115/7163
116/7163
121/7163
519/7132
154/7163
...
```

However, when I do so, some of those get formatted to a date (i.e. `5/7161` becomes `May-61`. Note that in the transfer to my `importWS`, Excel added 5/**1**/7161 on its own...then turned that into `May-61`. If I change it to `Number` then the cell changes its value completely, to `1921663.00`.  How do I prevent that from happening?

I'm copying *from* `ws` and copying *to* `importWS`:

```
    importWS.range(importWS.cells(2,4),importWS.cells(lastRow,4)).Value = _
ws.Range(ws.cells(2,7),ws.cells(lastRow,7)).Value
```

I've tried using `.Value2` and `.Text` and neither work.  I know I could loop through each cell in the range, and do like `importWS.cells(i,4).Value = "'" & ws.cells(i,7).Value` but would rather not, since I'm using the above range method to do this for multiple columns.

Comment: Try formatting the range like this. ws1.Range("A1:A12").NumberFormat = "@" before you copy the values in.  If Excel has no defined format it will try to figure out what you want, many times incorrectly assuming dates..

Comment: I applied that to my `ws` ranges first, to no avail. ( `ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, rawColArray(i)), ws.Cells(lastRow, rawColArray(i))).NumberFormat = "@"`)

Comment: Try the target range. It look like you are copying them to importWS.

Comment: Or try to use `.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Comment: I applied to both ranges, and tried it before and after the "pasting", and still shows incorrect format :/

Comment: If that doesn't work, I answered a question this morning that was basically the same issue, pull the data into a string, format the target cell, then copy the string into the target cell. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32381093/connvert-number-to-text-formatted-numbers-in-excel

Comment: @MatthewD - Thanks, I'll look in to that.  That method though requires looking at each cell, and not a range, correct? I don't mind doing this looping through cells in a range, but was curious if there's no solution to where I can stick with a range.  (I'll try actually using copy/paste with pasteSpecial).

Comment: @Nelly27281 - that did it! Switching to `.copy` and `.pasteSpecial` worked.  I tend to shy away from `.Copy` because (correct me if I'm wrong), it's more straightforward/better to set ranges equal instead.  But alas, I suppose there's a good reason to use `.copy` and this is one of them...?

Comment: Yes, that does it cell by cell. That is usually how i deal with small amounts of data.  Then if there is a need for performance I'll look to Excel to do the heavy lifting. I'm sure somebody will provide a one line solution.

Comment: @BruceWayne, first of all I didn't notice that you've asked the question (because I normally see in the answer zone). And yes there must be one liner solution as mentioned above. That suggestion suddenly strikes, so offered ;)

Comment: @MatthewD - thanks for the clarification.  This macro will run on worksheets with maybe 30 lines, and others with say 400 lines. I think copy/paste is fine for this.  Thanks though for your suggestion!

Comment: @BruceWayneSure thing, as always there are many ways to get it done.  Nelly27281 tracked it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preset the [Range.NumberFormat property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196401.aspx) to Text then read the [Range.Value2 property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193553.aspx) from the source.

```
with importWS
    .range(.cells(2, 4), .cells(lastRow, 4)).NumberFormat = "@"
    .range(.cells(2, 4), .cells(lastRow, 4)) = _
        ws.Range(ws.cells(2, 7), ws.cells(lastRow, 7)).value2
end with
```

Comment: Hm - nothing is being copied over. It's showing `ws.Range(ws.cells(...` as `Null` when I hover over with the mouse. (`importWS.Range(importWS.Cells(2, importColArray(i)), importWS.Cells(lastRow, importColArray(i))) = _
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, rawColArray(i)), ws.Cells(lastRow, rawColArray(i))).Text`).  (Even tried changing that to exactly how you have it, using `With`).

Comment: I get (respectively): `'[workbook.xls]Import'!$K$2:$K$117`  and `'[workbook.xls]raw'!$I$2:$I$117`. (note my actual columns are 11 and 9, not 4 and 7.)

Comment: Your edited solution works! Although, I did that earlier (setting the range numberformat to `@`), and it didn't work. Hmm.  Oh well, all is working now - thanks a ton to everybody!!

Comment: Needs to be `.Value2`, not `.Value`. Sorry about the foul-up. Halfway through the first cup of coffee.