# VBA code to pull max data from multiple spredsheets

Tags: excel, vba

The workbook has approx 50 spredsheets with a unique name. Each spreadsheet has data till column "F".
I would like to pull the spreadsheet name in one column and max data from column "C" in each spreadsheet to the next column though I know that the max data is from perticular spreadsheet.

Comment: What have you tried so far? To get you started, you'll probably want to look into loops so that you can cycle through through the sheets.

Comment: What do you mean by this: "and max data from column "C" in each spreadsheet to the next column though I know that the max data is from perticular spreadsheet."

Comment: Look at this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32384223/vba-copying-large-amounts-of-information-from-multiple-other-sheets/32384709#32384709 It shows how to loop through the sheets. When you are on each sheet do currentsheet.range("A" & lrow) = ws.name and then get the other data you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

How's something like this:

```
Sub get_Max()
Dim mainWS As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
Dim i%

Set mainWS = Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change this to meet your criteria. This is where the data will go

For i = Sheets.Count To 0 Step -1
    If Worksheets(i).Name = mainWS.Name Then Exit For
    ' Let's first list the sheet names in Column A of our mainWS
    mainWS.Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheets(i).Name
    ' Then get the max value from column C ('3').
    mainWS.Cells(i, 2).Value = WorksheetFunction.Max(Sheets(i).Range(Sheets(i).Columns(3), Sheets(i).Columns(3)))
Next i

End Sub
```